# Infinite loop when error occurs

Tags: java

When this code is run with a string as the input so that an error occurs it causes an infinite loop of the error message. I have tried inserting break; after the error message which does stop the loop but also stops the program. I would like it to loop back to the input request after an error occurs.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CubeUser                           
{                                               

    public static void main(String argv[])      
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean error = true;
        System.out.print("Please input the length of the cube:");                               
        while(error == true)
        {
            if (in.hasNextDouble())
            {
                double length = in.nextDouble();
                Cube cube1 = new Cube(length);                                                          
                System.out.println("The surface area of cube1 is " + cube1.calculateSurfArea() );       
                System.out.println("The volume of cube1 is " + cube1.calculateVolume() );
                error = false;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Please enter a numerical value for the cube's length.");
            }
        }
        in.close(); 

    }  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your scanner's cursor in case of error, otherwise it will keep reading the same value .

```
else {
     System.out.println("Please enter a numerical value for the cube's length.");
     in.next();
}
```

Off note: Use `if(error)` instead of `(error == true)`. Latter is bit frowned upon.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (in.hasNextDouble())
```

This will fire the first time, when the user types it in. When there is an error though, it doesn't give the user a chance to type in a `double` value, hence the infinite loop.

Restructure your loop like so:

```
String input;
while((input = in.nextDouble()) != null)
{
    // Force the user to type a value.
    // The rest of your code here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must read the input if it is not a double using e.g. `in.next()`, otherwise, `in.nextDouble()` will of course be true in the next iteration as there is still a non-double-value in the 'queue'.